# Why Does Including This Header File (w/ Header Guard) In 2 .CPP Files Cause Naming Collision?

Tags: c++, linker

Example.h:

```
#ifndef EXAMPLE_H
#define EXAMPLE_H

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>


namespace Test
{
    DWORD foo;
}

#endif
```

Example.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Example.h"
```

Example2.cpp:

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include "Example.h"
```

Main.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

This results in the linker error:

```
error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found   
error LNK2005: "unsigned long Test::foo" (?foo@Test@@3KA) already defined in Example.obj
```

This code will compile if "Example.h" is not included in "Example2.cpp". To my understanding, Example.h will only be included once in this example. If that is true, why is there a naming collision for `foo`?

Comment: Congratulations, you have discovered why global variables declared in a header file is evil.  I wish I could get this across to more people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Header guards only protect against multiple inclusion in the same [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) (source file). It doesn't protect against multiple inclusion in different translation units.

Therefore you define the variable `Test::foo` in both source files.

One solution is to mark the variable declarations in the header file as `extern`, and in a single source file basically duplicate the declarations from the header file as definitions (without the `extern` keyword).

Note that this only happens for variables, not for classes or functions or similar.

Comment: IMHO, a *better* solution is to eliminate the need for a global variable. :-)

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Not always possible or smart. Many things are global by nature, like an object factory.